# How do I return rows based on associated table row count in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

If I have a posts table and a comments table associated to it. Can I fetch a list of Post depending on the comment count in a single query? I.e. I only want a list of posts with 2 or more comments.

I'm aware this doesn't work but it illustrates what I wish to do.

```
SELECT * FROM posts p LEFT JOIN comments c ON c.post_id == p.id WHERE COUNT(c) > 2

POSTS
| id | title                 |
------------------------------
| 1  | Post with 1 comment   |
| 2  | Post with 3 comments  |
| 3  | Post with 4 comments  |
| 4  | Post with 0 comments  |

COMMENTS
| id | comment    | post_id  |
------------------------------
| 1  | Hello ...  | 1        |
| 2  | Good ...   | 2        |
| 3  | Hi ...     | 2        |
| 4  | Yes ...    | 2        |
| 5  | Good ...   | 3        |
| 6  | Hi ...     | 3        |
| 7  | Yes ...    | 3        |
… and so forth …
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer to your question is "yes" ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your query doesn't work is because the [`HAVING`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp) clause is used for conditions regarding aggregation. You cannot use the `WHERE` clause for this. To quote the linked page:

> The HAVING clause was added to SQL because the WHERE keyword could not
>   be used with aggregate functions.

Try the following query:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN comments c ON c.post_id = p.id
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 2;
```

Note also that because you are preforming aggregation, you will need to `GROUP BY` the post_id so you will see one resulting row for each post.

I would also like to point out that by grouping like this and only receiving one row for each post, you will be unable to properly display the comment information. If you would like to see the comments for all posts that have more than two comments, you will need to join your query above with the comment table:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM comments c
JOIN(
  SELECT p.id
  FROM posts p
  LEFT JOIN comments c ON c.post_id = p.id
  GROUP BY p.id
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 2) p ON p.id = c.post_id;
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1b0e0/4) example.

---

**EDIT**

If you want to search for posts that have more than two comments where one comes from a specific user, you can adjust the inner query with aggregation. You can add an extra condition to your `HAVING` clause to check that the `SUM(user_id = 1)` is greater than 0. Try this:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN comments c ON c.post_id = p.id
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 2 AND SUM(c.user_id = 1) > 0;
```

Here is an updated [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8fecb/1). I adjusted your sample data where user_id 1 only commented on a certain post, so you can see that it is indeed only that post that is returned.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation @McAdam331, Alex just beat you to it by a couple of minutes :/ I appreciate the extra input regarding the JOIN, thanks!

Comment: @AntonySastre I'm glad it helped. I do my best to help [explain the problem and solution](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274652/i-fixed-your-problem-better-than-thats-your-problem) and not just give the answer. Let me know if you have any questions. :)

Comment: Actually I do have a question :). What if I wanted to get the same results but filter for a i.e. user_id in the comment. So basically getting the same results but only get the posts, with more than 2 comments whereas at least one comment is from a given user?

Comment: Hm, realised that maybe that is a bit to complicated of a question for a comment…

Comment: @AntonySastre not complicated at all, give me a few seconds to edit my answer.

Comment: @AntonySastre I have edited the answer. I hope I understood your question properly, let me know if there is still confusion. The method I used of `SUM(condition)` is called conditional aggregation, which you can google if you want to learn more about it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78473/discussion-between-antony-sastre-and-mcadam331).

Answer (score 1):

You can't put condition with aggregating function like `SUM, MIN, MAX, COUNT etc` in `WHERE` clause. You should put such type of condition in `HAVING` clause after you set your `GROUP BY` statement.

That means `WHERE` executes for every record fetched from database (and for one record `MIN, MAX, COUNT etc` has no sense) and `HAVING` executes for every group row you asked for.

```
SELECT p.*, COUNT(*) 
FROM posts p 
LEFT JOIN comments c 
ON c.post_id = p.id 
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING COUNT(c.id) > 2
```